# Combining anonymous type functions

Tags: c#

This might be tricky.
I have 7 functions with nearly the same signature, but each of them invoke 7 other functions, again with similar signatures. I would like to combine them so I only have 2.
Here are 3 simplified versions of my functions:

```
private async Task<IList<T>> QueryAsync<T>(string storedProcedureName, OracleDynamicParameters parameters = null)
{

    // Get our models
    var models = await this._connection.QueryAsync<T>(storedProcedureName, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

    // Return our list
    return models.ToList();
}

private async Task<IList<T>> QueryAsync<T, TSecond>(string storedProcedureName, Func<T, TSecond, T> map, string splitOn, OracleDynamicParameters parameters = null)
{

    // Get our models
    var models = await this._connection.QueryAsync<T, TSecond, T>(storedProcedureName, map, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, splitOn: splitOn);

    // Return our list
    return models.ToList();
}

private async Task<IList<T>> QueryAsync<T, TSecond, TThird>(string storedProcedureName, Func<TFirst, TSecond, TThird, TFirst> map, string splitOn, OracleDynamicParameters parameters = null)
{

    // Get our models
    var models = await this._connection.QueryAsync<T, TSecond, TThird, T>(storedProcedureName, map, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, splitOn: splitOn);

    // Return our list
    return models.ToList();
}
```

What I would like to do is combine them somehow. So somehow check to see how many types have been passed and invoke the correct signature.
Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Comment: theres no good solution for combining these with generics. just look at Action<...> and Func<...>. Theres 16+ variants.

Comment: Code generation (think T4) FTW.

Comment: You can do some vodoo with Reflection, but ... on your own risk.

Comment: "I would like to combine them so I only have 2" which are these and why two?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
private async Task<IList<T>> QueryAsync<T, TSecond>(string storedProcedureName, Func<T, TSecond, T> map, string splitOn, OracleDynamicParameters parameters = null, ... other 3 params)
{

    //big switch here based on what are null or not
    var models = await this._connection.QueryAsync<...>(...);

    // Return our list
    return models.ToList();
}
```

This implies some logic on the params and null logic (nullable) on them: basically, if the last ones are null, leave them out.

This way you'll only have one big function (the most generic one).